# Pass getdate() in dynamic query as parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning everyone! I am building a dynamical query with parameters as seen in code below.

```
     c.Open();
                string columns = "(";
                string values = "(";
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in rootDataView.Columns)
                {
                    if (virtualColumns.Contains(column.Name))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        columns += column.Name + ",";
                        values += "@" + column.Name + " ,";
                    }
                }
                columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1) + ")";
                values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1) + ")";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into " + tableName + " " + columns + " Values " + values, c);
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in rootDataView.Columns)
                {
                    if (virtualColumns.Contains(column.Name))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (column.Name != "timeFrom")
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, editedRow.Cells[column.Name].Value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, System.DateTime.Now);
                        }
                    }
                }
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I have encountered a problem on this line

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, System.DateTime.Now);
```

I need to synchronize this time with SQL server, so I need to somehow pass `GETDATE()` as parameter, but when I enter it like this

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, "GetDate()");
```

it is being sent as string/varchar so it does not call function.

**I would like to know if there is a way to pass function as parameter, or if I need to replace the `@timeFrom` part of query string.**

EDIT:Please note the bold part, that is the question - I am asking for Yes/No and explanation why

Comment: Why don't you just paste 'GetDate()' directly into you query? I mean without parameter.

Comment: You need to create different command texts with / without parameter.

Comment: I want to know if there exists way I described, but your approach works too. @Mikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to try something like this:

```
            c.Open();
            string columns = "(";
            string values = "(";
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in rootDataView.Columns)
            {
                if (virtualColumns.Contains(column.Name))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    columns += column.Name + ",";
                    if (column.Name != "timeFrom")
                    {
                        values += "@" + column.Name + " ,";
                    } else {
                        //change in string
                        values += "GETDATE() ,";
                    }
                }
            }
            columns = columns.Substring(0, columns.Length - 1) + ")";
            values = values.Substring(0, values.Length - 1) + ")";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into " + tableName + " " + columns + " Values " + values, c);
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in rootDataView.Columns)
            {
                if (virtualColumns.Contains(column.Name))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    if (column.Name != "timeFrom")
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, editedRow.Cells[column.Name].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Basically, you do not treat timeFrom as parameter but you use GETDATE() to set it's value in the INSERT.

SQL Server and the client library that you are using, do not support passing parameters containing SQL. That is the reason why this construct will not work:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.Name, "GetDate()");
```

The only thing that is allowed to pass in AddWithValue is something that will translate to a literal SQL value.

Comment: The line has to be written like this `values += "GETDATE() ,";`, but I was asking for yes/no and explanation

Comment: @Hynek, you were right about the missing comma. I have added an explanation. Let me know if more is needed.